# Why does this test keeps failing?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, task-parallel-library, cancellationtokensource

The test is as follows:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void IncrementTestNegative() {

    CancellationTokenSource s = new CancellationTokenSource();
    s.CancelAfter(10);

    ManualResetEventSlim evt = new ManualResetEventSlim();

    bool breached = false;
    Task.Run(() => {
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        breached = true;
    }, s.Token).ContinueWith((t) => {
        evt.Set();
    });


    evt.Wait();
    Assert.IsFalse(breached);
}
```

If I provide a value of "0" to CancelAfter, then the test case succeeds. Why does this test keep failing with other values.

This is using MS Test framework within Visual Studio Express

Comment: Because the continuation will run even when the token passed to Run has already been cancelled, but the parent task will not. It fails for other values because cancellation is cooperative. The Run only checks the token before starting the task, not in the middle.

Comment: Cancelling the token **does not abort** the task. The `Thread.Sleep(200)` line seems to imply that you expect this to be aborted (after, say, 10ms)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cancelling the token **does not abort** the task. It merely sets the flag which you have to check for inside the task ([CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.iscancellationrequested(v=vs.110).aspx)). However, if the token is cancelled before the `Task` even starts, the `Task` will not run and will skip to the continuation.

The fact that you expect `breached` to be `false` after the tests implies that you expected the task to be aborted after the period specified with `CancelAfter`.

In other words, your `Thread.Sleep(200)` does not have a purpose, although the token will *probably* be cancelled at ~10ms after the task starts (you shouldn't expect very precise timing).

Comment: It is also a good practice to design long running operations with support of monitoring cancellation request, if possible.